# Unzip File in Dataflow Before Reading

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Our client is uploading files into GCS, but they are zipped. Is there any way, using the Java Dataflow SDK, in which we can run through all the zipped files, unzip the file, combine all the resulting .csv files into one file, and then only do the `TextIO` transforms?

**EDIT**

To answer jkffs's questions,

1. Well I don't really *need* to combine them all into a single file, it would just be much easier from a reading perspective.
2. They are ZIP files, not GZ or BZ or anything else. Each ZIP contains multiple files. The files names are not really significant, and yes, I would actually prefer it TextIO transparently decompresses and concatenates all the files, on a per-archive basis.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you explain why you want to combine all the .csv files into one before processing them further - do you need to process the file sequentially rather than in parallel? Is there any parallelizable processing after that?

Comment: Also, can you tell more about your zip files? Are they really .zip, or .gz/.bz2?  (TextIO currently supports gzip and bzip2 compression - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Read#withCompressionType-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO.CompressionType- , however not .zip files) If it's .zip, are there many files inside each .zip file, or just one? Are the filenames inside the archive significant? E.g. if TextIO transparently decompressed and concatenated all files in the zip archive, would that work for you?

Comment: @jkff I updated the question with some answers!

Answer (score 6):

because I had the same problem and only came to this 1 year old and quite incomplete solution. Here is a full example on how to unzip files on google dataflow:

```
public class SimpleUnzip {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleUnzip.class);

public static void main(String[] args){
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(
            PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

    GcsUtilFactory factory = new GcsUtilFactory();
    GcsUtil util = factory.create(p.getOptions());
    try{
        List<GcsPath> gcsPaths = util.expand(GcsPath.fromUri("gs://tlogdataflow/test/*.zip"));
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(GcsPath gcsp: gcsPaths){
            paths.add(gcsp.toString());
        }
        p.apply(Create.of(paths))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new UnzipFN()));
        p.run();

        }
    catch(Exception e){
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }


}

public static class UnzipFN extends DoFn<String,Long>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2015166770614756341L;
    private long filesUnzipped=0;
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
        String p = c.element();
        GcsUtilFactory factory = new GcsUtilFactory();
        GcsUtil u = factory.create(c.getPipelineOptions());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100000000];
        try{
            SeekableByteChannel sek = u.open(GcsPath.fromUri(p));
            InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(sek);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            while(ze!=null){
                LOG.info("Unzipping File {}",ze.getName());
                WritableByteChannel wri = u.create(GcsPath.fromUri("gs://tlogdataflow/test/" + ze.getName()), getType(ze.getName()));
                OutputStream os = Channels.newOutputStream(wri);
                int len;
                while((len=zis.read(buffer))>0){
                    os.write(buffer,0,len);
                }
                os.close();
                filesUnzipped++;
                ze=zis.getNextEntry();

            }
            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    c.output(filesUnzipped);
    }

    private String getType(String fName){
        if(fName.endsWith(".zip")){
            return "application/x-zip-compressed";
        }
        else {
            return "text/plain";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Dataflow / Apache Beam support ZIP-compressed files in `TextIO` automatically: `TextIO.read().from(filepattern)` will automatically decompress files matching the filepattern according to their extension, and `.zip` is one of the supported formats - in that case it will implicitly concatenate all files inside the `.zip` into a single file, and parse lines of text from that.

You can also specify compression type explicitly using `TextIO.read().from(filepattern).withCompressionType(...)` if the files don't have an extension.

Comment: Worth noting that this is only for the Java library. As of yet the Python library still only supports BZIP and GZIP2 (https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.3.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/filesystem.html#CompressionTypes) and I can't find any pull requests on github to do with adding support.